# Need help with image to be written on

Tags: cognito-forms

I am creating a breast questionnaire for patients who will be getting a mammogram. You will notice an image at the bottom of [this page](https://www.cognitoforms.com/LifeSavingImages1/BreastHistoryQuestionnaire). It is for the technician performing the mammogram to indicate areas of concern.

Is there any way to make it so that the image can be written on?

I tried doing this on my touch screen and iPad but because its an image...can't really write on it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

No, we do not have a way to draw, or make updates to an image that has been added to a Cognito Form.